# Given max length of $x,y$ and angle, how to find $x,y$ based on angle.

Tags: trigonometry

Horrendous at math. Making a game where object rotates around another obj. Stuck on this problem.

[image]

$45^\circ = (5,5)$

I have the max length of $x$ (opposite) and $y$ (adjacent) and the degree of the angle. When I change the angle the hypotenuse should point to the new co-ordinate.

[image]
$65^\circ = (5,3)$

Comment: Are you trying to stay on the square with vertices $(5,5),(5,-5),(-5,-5),(-5,5)$? And find the co-ordinates of a point A such that , if O=(0,0) and C=(5,0), angle AOC measures x degrees, for specified x?

Comment: @tropicalmemes How is $65^\circ = (5,3)$?

Comment: 65∘=(5,3) is just an arbitrary example. It's just to illustrate the point that if I change the angle, the x,y will change accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x, y)=(R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta)$

These are [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). $R$ is the distance of the point from the origin.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I'm pretty trash at math. Would R be the hypot?

Comment: http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Coordinates/polar_-_rectangular_conversion.htm oops